# How do I use the data returned by a cURL request?

Tags: php, curl

I am passing an array for a php page to test but I can not get the data!

```
$data = array(
              "user_id" => $login->id,
              "discount_id" => $discount,
              "product_id" => $product_id->id,
              "date_payment" => $test->id
            );

$fields_string = http_build_query($data);

$url = "http://localhost/dev/felipe/request-checkout.php";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);

$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);
```

page.php:

```
extract($_POST);

$user_id =  $_POST['user_id']; 
$discount_id =  $_POST['discount_id'];
$product_id =  $_POST['product_id'];
$data_payment =  $_POST['date_payment'];


echo $user_id . ' - ' . $discount_id . ' - ' . $product_id . ' - ' . $data_payment;
```

show null in $result in cURL. what I'm missing? how do I use the data and have a response which I did cURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl_exec($ch)` returns string in this format: `"1 - 2 - 3 - 4"`.

When you try to run `json_decode()` on this string, it returns null because this is not correct json format.

---

Instead of the `echo $user_id . ' - ' . $discount_id . ' - ' . $product_id . ' - ' . $data_payment;`, you can endode an array/object to json string:

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```